# Session is not working for multiple language in PHP website

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to build multi language website (english and marathi). Default language marathi is working fine. When on the about.php page and try to change the language to english it redirecting to the index.php page (language getting changed to english) but I have to be on same page (about.php) with language change as english. Then Also when I click on another page it is still showing default language. May be issue with session or below code... Requesting some assistance and help with this. Thanks in advance.

```
 <script>
    function set_language(){
        var language=jQuery('#language').val();
        window.location.href='http://127.0.0.1/projects/website/?language='+language;
    }
</script>
```

index.php Page is

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include('language.php');
   $en_select='';
   $mr_select='';       
   $language='';
   
   if(!isset($_GET['language'])){
    $mr_select='selected';  
    $language='mr';
   }else if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='mr'){
    $_SESSION["language"] = "mr"; 
    $mr_select='selected';  
    $language='mr';
   }
   else{
    $en_select='selected';
    $language='en';
    $_SESSION["language"] = "en";
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Welcome</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
   </head>
   <body class="is-preload">
         <!-- Header -->
         <header id="header">
            <ul class="icons">
               <li>
                  <select onchange="set_language()" name="language" id="language">
                     <option value="mr" selected>मराठी</option>
                     <option value="en" >English</option>
                  </select>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </header>

         <script>
            function set_language(){
                var language=jQuery('#language').val();
                window.location.href='http://127.0.0.1/projects/website/?language='+language;
            }
         </script>

         <!-- Banner -->
         <section id="banner">
            <div class="content">
               <header>
                  <h2><?php echo $top_title[$language]['0']?></h2>
               </header>
         </section> 

         <!-- Menu -->
         <nav id="menu">
            <header class="major">
               <h2>Menu</h2>
            </header>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.php"><?php echo $top_nav[$language]['0']?></a></li>
               <li><a href="about.php"><?php echo $top_nav[$language]['1']?></a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

language.php page is like below

```
<?php
   $top_nav=array(
      'en'=>array(
               'Home',
               'About Us',),
   
      'mr'=>array(
               'मुख्यपृष्ठ',
               'आमच्याबद्दल')
   );
   
   $top_title = array(
      'en' => array('You are Welcome !'), 
      'mr' => array('आपले स्वागत आहे !')
   );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$SESSION` as a variable, but I guess you want to use `$_SESSION` instead? If not, please update your question with some details from `language.php`.

You are setting the language in a session, but no never use that session to read the language.

This code will work:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('language.php');

// Set English as default language
$language='en';

// set the language if in session
if (isset($_SESSION["language"])) {
    $language = $_SESSION["language"];
}

// Set language if in url (and store it in session)
if (isset($_GET["language"])) {
    $language = $_GET["language"];
    $_SESSION["language"] = $_GET["language"];
}
?>
```

And instead of setting the `$en_select` variable, you can reuse the `$language` variable instead:

```
<select onchange="set_language()" name="language" id="language">
    <option value="mr"<?php if ($language === 'mr') { ?> selected<?php } ?>>मराठी</option>
    <option value="en"<?php if ($language === 'en') { ?> selected<?php } ?>>English</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for quick update.. I am using $_SESSION and not variable .  In language.php file I am storing the data for en and mr language. I am outputting the array based on language (as per url in script) in index.php as `<?php echo $top_nav[$language]['0']?>`.. I tried your code by changing $_SESSION but not working when switching to other page, it is showing default language.

Comment: Try to add `var_dump($_SESSION['language']);` to see what's happening.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['language']);` showing the values as **string(2) "mr"))**

Comment: That's great! Fixed a typo in my answer. Can you try the code?

Comment: When on about.php page and clicking the english language it is redirecting me to the index.php page with default language marathi.

Comment: thanks @Stephan. It working fine but getting the error when switching to another page `Notice: Undefined index: language in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Projects/SGP/language/top_lang_include.php on line 11`. for the line `if ($_GET["language"]) {`

Comment: thanks @Stephan appreciate your assistance and help.  Session is working fine.. when I click to change the language it is changing but it is redirecting to index.php always. how can keep the session and language on same.

Comment: Sorry, this is something you should find out yourself first. I've updated my answer multiple times with small details you could have find yourself.

Comment: it is resolved.. thanks @Stephan for your valuable assistance .